# How to find the coordinates where the altitude of a triangle intersects the base?

Tags: geometry

I have a triangle with known, but random coordinates for each point.

Let's assume A(3,4), B(5,7), C(13.5,8.5)

[image: Triangle]

How can I find the coordinates where the altitude from point B intersects the AC segment?

I've calculated the length of BD, AD and DC segments, the slope of AC but I'm not sure what's next.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculation of the Coordinates of the Intersection Point of the Altitude and the Base of a Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596900/calculation-of-the-coordinates-of-the-intersection-point-of-the-altitude-and-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line $AC$ is defined by $$\frac{y-y_A}{x-x_A}=\frac{y_C-y_A}{x_C-x_A}$$

Then we know $AC(x)=m_{AC}x+b_{AC}$, where $m_{AC}$ is the slope and $b_{AC}$ is the y-intercept (both are known).

Let $BD(x)=m_{BD}x+b_{BD}$. Then $m_{BD}=\frac{-1}{m_{AC}}$ and $b_{BD}=y_B-m_{BD}x_B$.

Now solve $AC(x)=BD(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The line $AC$ can be denoted by the equation $y = \frac{3}{7}x + \frac{19}{7}$.

The altitude is perpendicular to $AC$, so it will have slope $-\frac{7}{3}$ and go through $(5,7)$, so it is the line $y' = -\frac{7}{3}x + \frac{56}{3}$.

Now just solve those equations:

$$\begin{split}
y &= \frac{3}{7}x + \frac{19}{7} \\
y &= -\frac{7}{3}x + \frac{56}{3}
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
x_? = \frac{x_A \dfrac{y_C - y_A}{x_C - x_A} + y_B + x_B \dfrac{x_C - x_A}{y_C - y_A}}{\dfrac{y_C - y_A}{x_C - x_A} + \dfrac{x_C - x_A}{y_C - y_A}},\\
y_? = \frac{y_C - y_A}{x_C - x_A} \left( \frac{x_A \dfrac{y_C - y_A}{x_C - x_A} + y_B + x_B \dfrac{x_C - x_A}{y_C - y_A}}{\dfrac{y_C - y_A}{x_C - x_A} + \dfrac{x_C - x_A}{y_C - y_A}} - x_A \right).
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your answers (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Tried Silesian University of Science solution. It's not correct in situation with vertical line (Yc === Ya), because we have division by zero at this case. Correctly solution is (A(x1,y1), C(x2,y2), B(x3,y3), D(x,y)): k = ((x3-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y3-y1)*(y2-y1))/ (pow(x2-x1, 2) + pow(y2-y1, 2)); x = x1 + k * (x2-x1); y = y1 + k * (y2-y1);