# Calculation of the Coordinates of the Intersection Point of the Altitude and the Base of a Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Given any triangle $\Delta ABC$, what are the coordinates of the point $D$, along the line $\overline{BC}$, such that $\overline{AD}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{BC}$?

For example, given the triangle $\Delta ABC$, where $(A_x = -1,\ A_y = 4)$, $(B_x = -1,\ B_y = 2)$, and $(C_x = 5,\ C_y = 1)$, the solution is $(D_x = 1.4,\ D_y = -0.8)$. I know the solution to this particular example from watching this [video explaining how to calculate altitudes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuEbWkF5lcM). This was one of the examples used in the video, but it was calculated using a multi-step process.

I know that the slope of line segment $\overline{BC}$ is the negative inverse of $m_\overline{BC}$.

$$m_\overline{BC} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$
$$m_\overline{BC} = \frac{1 - (-2)}{5 - (-1)}$$
$$m_\overline{BC} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$m_\overline{AD} = \frac{-1}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$m_\overline{AD} = -2$$

Despite being able to calculate the slope of the line, I’m not sure at what point it will intersect $\overline{BC}$.

I am searching for a general formula to calculate the $x$ and $y$ Cartesian coordinates of point $D$. Please provide a explicit solution for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $D$ denoted by $D_x$ an $D_y$, respectively.

Comment: General coordinates for $A,B,C$? Or specific?

Comment: What do you mean by a solution in the form $D_x$, $D_y$.?

Comment: Maybe related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317578/how-to-find-the-coordinates-where-the-altitude-of-a-triangle-intersects-the-base

Comment: Is $D_x$ the x-coordinate of point $D$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I want the specific coordinates for $D$ for any triangle $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, exactly. And $D_y$ is the y-coordinate of $D$.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I’m trying to find the formulas for $D_x$ and $D_y$, the Cartesian coordinates of the point $D$, given three specific points of a triangle $\Delta ABC$. I found that other question but it does not provide the solution in the form I’m searching for and I don’t know how to convert it into that form. I’ve attempted to edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step approach.

$1.$ As we have the coordinates of $B$ and $C$, we can compute a **unit** normal vector to the line segment $BC$. This is how yo may do this

$$\begin{align}
{\bf{L}}&= {\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C\\
&=(x_B-x_C){\bf{i}}+(y_B-y_C){\bf{j}} \\
\\
{\bf{N}}&= {\bf{k}} \times {\bf{L}}\\
&=-(y_B-y_C){\bf{i}}+(x_B-x_C){\bf{j}} \\
\\
{\bf{N}} \cdot {\bf{L}} &= 0 \\
\\
{\bf{n}} &= \frac{\bf{N}}{\|\bf{N}\|} \\
&= \frac{{\bf{k}} \times {\bf{L}}}{\|\bf{L}\|} \\
&= \frac{{\bf{k}} \times ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C)}{\|{\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C\|}\\
&=\frac{-(y_B-y_C){\bf{i}}+(x_B-x_C){\bf{j}}}{\sqrt{(x_B-x_C)^2+(y_B-y_C)^2}}
\end{align}$$

$2.$ We can observe from the figure below that

$$d = ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_A)\cdot{\bf{n}}$$

so we have found the length of $AD$.

[image]

$3.$ The coordinates of $D$ will be

$$\begin{align}
{\bf{x}}_D &= {\bf{x}}_A + d{\bf{n}} \\
&= {\bf{x}}_A + [({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_A)\cdot{\bf{n}}]{\bf{n}} \\
\\
&= {\bf{x}}_A + \left[({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_A)\cdot\frac{{\bf{k}} \times ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C)}{\|{\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C\|}\right]\frac{{\bf{k}} \times ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C)}{\|{\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C\|} \\
\end{align}$$

and finally

$$\boxed{{\bf{x}}_D= {\bf{x}}_A + \frac{{\bf{k}} \cdot \left[ ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C) \times ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_A) \right] \ }{\|{\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C\|^2} {\bf{k}} \times ({\bf{x}}_B-{\bf{x}}_C)}$$

you can write the above vector equation as the following two scalar ones

$$\boxed{
\begin{align}
x_D &= x_A - \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_B-x_C & y_B-y_C \\
x_B-x_A & y_B-y_A \\
\end{vmatrix}}{(x_B-x_C)^2+(y_B-y_C)^2} (y_B-y_C) \\
\\
y_D &= y_A + \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_B-x_C & y_B-y_C \\
x_B-x_A & y_B-y_A
\end{vmatrix}}{(x_B-x_C)^2+(y_B-y_C)^2} (x_B-x_C)
\end{align}
}$$

Also, [here is a MAPLE file](http://pc.cd/eOortalK) that can help the reader of this post for the computation of final formulas mentioned here and the verification of the example mentioned in the question.

Comment: @HR Okay, I’ve accepted your answer and deleted my previous comments. I will delete this one as soon as I see you’ve deleted yours.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:(x_1,y_1)$, $B:(x_2,y_2)$, $C:(x_3,y_3)$.
So the equation of line through $BC$ will be, $$y-y_2=(\frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3})(x-x_2)$$
And thus, the slope of altitude will be negative inverse, 
$$-\left(\frac{x_2-x_3}{y_2-y_3}\right)$$
And thus, the equation of the line:
$$y=c-\left(\frac{x_2-x_3}{y_2-y_3}\right)x$$
Putting in the values and solving for $c$, gives the equation, 
$$y=y_1+\left(\frac{x_2-x_3}{y_2-y_3}\right)x_1-\left(\frac{x_2-x_3}{y_2-y_3}\right)x$$
Now just solve the two equations simultaneously.

---

Hint: To do that, let
$$\left(\frac{y_2-y_3}{x_2-x_3}\right)=m$$
So we have to solve $$y=y_2+m(x-x_2)$$
$$y=y_1+\frac1mx_1-\frac1mx$$

---

This is an elementary approach, a slightly more advanced approach would be to rotate the triangle, so its base is parallel with the x-axis. There are various formulae for it for example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta \ -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta \ \ \ \ \ \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
the rotation matrix. Or [Rotation Formulae](http://www.mathematics-online.org/inhalt/aussage/aussage444/). 
Then translate it so that one of the base vertices are on the origin, and then use the method above, it would simplify a hell lot of a things.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an answer in the form I requested? To clarify, I’m looking for the Cartesian coordinates (both $D_x$ and $D_y$) of point $D$, given three specific points of a triangle $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: It would be a very tedious form. Better option would be to substitute the values in these two equations above and solve them simultaneously.